# How to add applications to GNOME (3.16) Control Center (no Unity)

Tags: gnome, system-settings, gnome-control-center

Previous threads on AskUbuntu are from 2012 and the method used there is no longer supported. It looks like GNOME has closed off the control center for modifications (simply editing .desktop files won't work) and is a pain if you're not using Unity (said that even that way would be possible nowadays). Has anyone tried to add applications to the GNOME Control Center in recent versions and succeeded? I would be glad to know if so and how :)